# Flutter не видит Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, flutter

Как на Windows решить данную проблему?

Установил flutter, установил Android Studio.

Kоманда:

> flutter doctor 
>   выводит такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но пути у меня прописаны, что ему нужно еще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

переменные среды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно убрать знак `$` из имени переменной. Она называется `ANDROID_HOME`, а не `$ANDROID_HOME`.

Comment: правильно, знак $ убрал. Но помогло не это. нужно было в переменную PATH прописать путь до SDK. 1. ...android-sdk\tools\ 2. ...android-sdk\platform-tools\

Comment: Вероятно, особенности флаттера. Андроид Студии достаточно до корневой папки. А ``ANDROID_SDK_HOME``, похоже, расположение эмуляторов, а не сдк.

Comment: видимо это из-за того что я при установке выбрал место назначение папки c SDK путь не по умолчанию, а изменил его на диск Д